# Cables Interaction Required

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have watched various tutorials on making cables react with the movement of the objects they're connected to. But said tuts are starting from scratch. See the image. The cables are already in situ.

I've added a circle to the model enabling 'head' rotation. So now I need to have the cables move accordingly when I rotate said head - just the section of the cables between the two arrows. I'm assigning to a group, adding a Cloth effect and hooking the cables to the model etc - but I just can't get the right reaction, it just doesn't work or I explode the rig.

Some pointers would be great. I guess I can add the .Blend file in the next message if required. I'm no model maker as you can tell.

Many thanks.

[image: Industrial robot with cables]

Comment: Hi @Chris. Many thanks for that. Excuse my inexperience. Will it work if I parent a bezier to the cables?

Comment: you are welcome